# Building an ETF portfolio: Is it even possible to diversify?

Tags: savings, etf, vanguard, diversification

I want to start investing my money. I've decided to invest a monthly fixed amount by buying ETFs. I am currently investigating different ETFs to decide on what my portfolio allocation will look like.

After a bit of research, I found out that a good place to start is to look at what Vanguard offers. So I did just that.

I noticed that Vanguard offers ETF that don't seem that differ much. For instance, how different can the 1) Vanguard Mega Cap (MGC), 2) Vanguard Mega Cap value (MGK) and 3) Vanguard Mega Cap Growth (MGV) really be?

To answer that questions, I ran the correlations on some of Vanguard's funds

[Correlation Matrix on Vanguard ETF's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pggEF.png)
:

So this seems to answer my question. The funds mentioned above have a correlation > 99.7%.

We also see that the correlations is extremely high on a number of these funds. For instance between the Vanguard S&P 500 (VOO) and the Vanguard Total Stock Market (VTI) we have 99.97% and between the Vanguard S&P 500 (VOO) and the Vanguard Extended Market (VXF) we have 99.2%.

With numbers like these, combining these ETF's in a portfolio makes no sense since they all move exactly the same way. I should therefore just pick one by looking at the traded volume and the management fees.

For the sake of the ETF, let's pick the Vanguard Total Stock Market (VTI).

In the correlation matrix, I see that 2 funds stand out by having a lower correlation with the VTI. These are the Vanguard FTSE Emerging Markets (VWO) and Vanguard FTSE Europe ETF (VGK). There have - respectively - a  correlation - compared to VTI - of 69% and 85%. Also, their own correlation is of 79%.

So here we have it. On one hand a non-diversified portfolio composed only of 1 ETF, the VTI. And on the other a diversified portfolio composed of 3 ETF's: the VTI, the VWO and the VGK. Let's assume an allocation of 50%, 25% and 25%. In the following example, I will also assume perfect monthly re-balancing.

Let's have a look at the results.

[VTI ETF versus Diversified Portfolio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcRZL.png)

We can see that both portfolios show pretty much the same story. 
Naturally, I've also computed the correlation between both portfolios. The result is 98%.
With such a high correlation, it's no surprise that the diversified portfolio slightly under-performs: the management fees twice as high!

Portfolio VTI: 100% * 0.04% = 0.04%

Portfolio "Diversified": 50% * 0.04% + 25% * 0.14% + 25% *0.10% = 0.08%

From this little experiment it seems like the only sensible move is to put all my money on the cheapest Total Stock ETF I can find (basically any of the "S&P 500", "Extended Market", "Total Stock", "Mega Cap", etc. funds).

What do you think on this? Am I missing part of the picture? Does diversification hold benefits I haven't considered? Am I looking at diversification in the wrong places (maybe I should consider industry rather than geography)?

Any insights on this is more than welcome! :-)

Update: I have added 2 more funds to the correlation matrix: a small-cap ETF (VB) and a mid-cap ETF (VO).
[Updated Correlation Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHrgi.jpg)

Comment: None of those look like commodities ETFs/ETNs, maybe find one of those to compare against.  Also, to clarify, you're only wondering about whether within an ETF portfolio you can diversify (further than the diversification inherent in an ETF)? You're already planning to diversify investments outside of your ETF purchases, right?

Comment: I bought into VTI, a small-cap, a mid-cap, and a foreign developed. Boom. Diversity.

Comment: @HartCO: 1) I can look into commidities ETF. This is the sort of thing I was thinking about when I wrote "Am I looking at diversification in the wrong places". I can look into commodities and I can play with currencies. Any other ideas?
2) No, I am not planning in having other investment outside of my ETF portfolio. Do you think I should already think about this? I figured I had a few years ahead of me ...

Comment: You can't invest a fixed dollar amount in an ETF unless the ETF (or your brokerage) allows you to buy fractional shares: shares are generally sold in integer numbers and preferably in multiples of 100 (round lots) to minimize brokerage fees.

Comment: FYI, if you buy Vanguard ETFs on Vanguard, there are 0 trade fees. Of course, the funds have a fee, like 0.15%.

Comment: Many of these ETFs are highly correlated because they own many of the same stocks with similar weightings, and these stocks account for a large proportion of each ETF. "Mega cap" seems to be more of a marketing term right now: if you look at the actual holdings and weightings, it is virtually identical to Large cap (VV) and the S&P 500 (VOO), without the smallest 250 or so stocks in VV and VOO. VXF holds nearly every liquid U.S. stock that isn't in VOO, and since VTI attempts to hold all liquid U.S. stocks, it is effectively a market-cap-weighted combination of VOO and VXF (ie 90% VOO+10% VXF)

Comment: If you're looking for less correlation between equity ETFs, try looking at funds that don't own the same underlying stocks. Some possibilities here would be US small-cap (VB), US mid-cap (VO), and VOO, or the total US stock market (VTI) and the total non-US stock market (VXUS)

Comment: @JonathanTyson and WakeDemons3: Thanks a lot for your input!
You both mentionned small- and mid-cap funds so I just had a look at those. I added them in my correlation matrix. You can see that the small-cap and mid-cap are correlated at 99.82% and both are > 99.5% correlated to VTI. So it seems that they don't in fact offer any additional diversification, right?

Comment: Also note that in this century, world-wide stock markets have been [highly correlated](http://www.businessinsider.com/global-stock-correlations-falling-2017-7)

Comment: @VictorOnline that does appear to be the case over the last 10 years. Historically though, there was a [small-cap and value-premium](http://www.moneychimp.com/articles/index_funds/small_mid.htm), ie those stocks outperformed large-cap and growth stocks over long periods of time. Whether that holds in the future is anyone's guess

Comment: @JonathanTyson I ran the correlation for the longest period available (since creation of VO and VB): a bit over 14 years.
I'm getting the impression these ETF's were never a good deal. Since their inception they moved exactly like the VTI, for a higher price. You mentionned above that the "Mega cap" seemed to be more of a marketing term. It's looking a lot like "Small cap", "Mid cap", "Extended market", etc are more of the same.

Comment: @WakeDemon3 (and OP) Be a little careful VTI includes most of the stocks in the small-cap and mid-cap indexes.  So while the foreign developed fund actually diversifies your portfolio.  The small/mid cap funds don't diversify your portfolio but instead only _tilt_ it toward smaller companies.  This may be what you want... but the difference is important.

Comment: I don't see your point. You can't diversify by cherry-picking funds that are almost the same by design? Obviously. A fund that by definition covers *the entire stock market* overlaps with other stock funds? Obviously. Vanguard does have other ETFs that have much less overlap. VTI (total stock market) + VT (total world stock) covers almost all the stock in the world; add in BND (total US bond market) and BNDX (total int'l bond) and you have basically every stock and bond in the world. How is that not diversified?

Comment: @Kevin well said.  Small detail though.  VT actually includes VTI as well.  So, VT covers almost every stock in the world by itself.  Though you can get essentially the same coverage for cheaper using VTI, VEA and VWO.

Answer (score 3):

As these Vanguard index ETF hold many stocks, this might be clearer if you consider the underlying portfolio of stocks that you end up with when buying these funds.  For instance, in your first example [Vanguard Mega Cap](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=3138&FundIntExt=INT&funds_disable_redirect=true#tab=2) is an ETF of all mega cap stocks including almost all of the stocks in Vanguard Mega Cap Value and Vanguard Mega Cap Growth (check the holdings for each).  You can (essentially) make MGC by combining MGK and MGV.  So, adding these two funds does not diversify a portfolio with just MGC.

However, VTI (US stocks) holds an entirely different set of stocks than VGK (Europe) and VWO (Emerging).  So holding all three is diversifying in this case.  To understand diversification, it's better to check correlation amongst the funds as you are interested in to see how they relate to each other.  Now, the correlations amongst these three funds may be rather high all around ~0.75 (daily, 5/3/2018, last two years, Bloomberg), but that is still a good amount of diversification.  I think it is great you are checking fees closely not enough people do that, but a tiny extra fee of 0.04% is likely worth that extra diversification.

If you [look at the holdings some more](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0970&FundIntExt=INT&funds_disable_redirect=true#tab=2) you will notice that funds like VTI are already broadly diversified across industries (see the "Equity sector diversification" section.  It is also diversified across company size.  You can check and see that the stocks in MGC are in VTI but VTI holds smaller stocks as well.  Besides geography and size, other common diversification directions (with even lower correlations to equity) are bonds (BND), real estate (VNQ) and commodities (though I find commodities tough to recommend).

Addition to clarify:

> We can see that both portfolios show pretty much the same story

Actually those two portfolios (100% VTI and Diversified) are very different over the time period you explore.  The [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) being high only means they tend to change in the same "direction" (gains/losses) day-after-day but the magnitude and drift of the changes matters a lot as well, especially over time. 
 The graph you have there shows the diversified portfolio beating the other portfolio significantly during some periods and losing in others.

Correlation is just one useful tool among many toward [building a diversified portfolio](https://advisors.vanguard.com/iwe/pdf/ICRPC.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
I added 2 new funds in my correlation matrix. You can see that the small-cap and mid-cap are correlated at 99.82% and both are > 99.5% correlated to VTI. So it seems that they don't in fact offer any additional diversification. This is why I am not focusing on the underlying components on the ETF so much. Although these ETF's may hold different stocks, if they are perfectly correlated, why bother?  The only thing I see here is that VTI, VO and VB perform in the same way except VTI had smaller management fees (I agree however that 0.01% wouldn't kill me :-) )

Comment: Regarding bond and commodity ETFs, this is the first item on my to-do-list. I'm still focusing on the stock portion of the portfolio but I really need to consider these as well. To be honest I even forgot about real estate so thanks a lot for that!

Comment: It is very important to understand the underlying components so that you can understand why funds are correlated and why they may or may not diversify.  For instance, VTI includes most of the stocks in the mid-cap and small-cap funds and that is _why_ adding those funds does not diversify a 100% VTI portfolio instead it would tilt your portfolio toward smaller stocks.

Comment: Two funds may be highly correlated during certain periods and less correlated during others.  Understanding what you are buying will help you understand if those correlations will be persistent over time.  For instance, VTI and VWO go through periods where they are more or less correlated, but because you are buying an entirely different set of stocks with VWO you can have more faith that owning both will have a diversification effect.

Comment: You have mentionned
_"The correlation being high only means they tend to change in the same "direction" (gains/losses) day-after-day but the magnitude and drift of the changes matters a lot as well, especially over time."_
I think correlation measures more than the direction. I have a limited amount of characters so I can't get into it, but believe the magnitude of the changes is being captured in the correlation coefficient.
Are you sure of what you are saying? I could be wrong, my  last statistics classes was a while ago :)

Comment: Check out the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence.  It's worth a full read here, but for a quick view look at those graphs on the side.  There are a number of lines with correlation 1 but they all have different slopes. Correlation is a measure of how close to "linear" a relationship between two variables is but not the magnitude (slope) of that relationship.

Comment: I'm trying to get it :)
If fund A and B are perfectly correlated, when the price of A goes up/down by X , then the price of B goes up/down by X*Y. The correlation of 1 doesn't tell us the value of Y, it just tells us that it is a constant superior to 0. So we could have a situation where the price of A is 100 at a given moment and fluctuates between 90 and 110 while the price of B is 100 and fluctuates between 0 and 200. (1/2)

Comment: In that case then I could create 2 equivalent portfolios. Portfolio 1 will hold 10 units of A while portfolio 2 will hold 900 cash and 1 unit of B. Both Portfolio will be worth 1000 at the beginning and fluctuate between 900 and 1100 over the period, in exactly the same way.
If this is correct then the point is that although 2 funds may have different magnitudes of gain/loss, if they're correlation is 1, this is not relevant for me. I should just chose the most convenient for me. (2/2)

Comment: (part 1/2) Yes that is it.  (part 2/2) Oh it is still very relevant. First, even a perfectly linear relationship has a constant (a drift) B = const + Y*X if that constant is large and negative you definitely want A.  Second, these correlations, slopes (Y) and especially that drift change over time.  VTI may have had a high correlation with VEA and VWO recently but if a real trade war starts, for instance, those could swing around wildly.  This is where a real diversified portfolio shines.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for taking the time!
I didn't understand the part about the constant, could you explain a little bit more what you mean? Is fund A & B have a correlation of 1 then they have a perfectly linear relation ship that can be described with y=ax+b. Is this "b" the constant you are referring to? Isn't that just the cash allocation?
Second, I think I see your point nonetheless. Although 2 funds may be extremely correlated, if they do indeed hold different assets, diversification could still be worth it. (1/3)

Comment: The reason is that the different stocks held may move together today because globalization is so strong. Indeed, if big US companies operate all around the world, then it makes sense that an US ETF will be the same as a World ETF or as a combination of US+EU+Rest of World. However, there's no guarantee that this is true in all business cycle (although it seems to have been the case for the last 15 years) nor that this will always be the case (e.g. in the case of protectionists measures). (2/3)

Comment: With that in mind, buying ETFs composed of different assets mays not be any different than buying a single World ETF _today_ but could help me in the long run. Considering the fact that diversifying ETF only means a little bit more expenses for transactions and management fees and is still a very "manageable" portfolio (easy to understand and monitor), this could be the winning strategy for a long term lazy investor.
Correct? Did I misunderstand / leave out anything important? (3/3)

Comment: (1/3) in this example "b" is how much better/worse asset y performed over asset x over the period tested.  Literally.  Like US assets have returned more money than European assets over recent times.  (2/3) yup you get it.

Comment: (3/3) Yes. Buying a world index ETF is a good, lazy way to get (essentially) as diversified as possible in the equity space while keeping your fees and the amount of work involved manageable.